# ParametricRegion

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I need to solve a PDE inside a region confined between two waves (as in the figure below). The waves amplitude and period do not matter at the present point (they can be arbitrary) I just need an efficient way to describe such a region via the ParametricRegion command.

[image]

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
ParametricRegion[{x, y Cos[π x]}, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]
```

Comment: Great, clear and right to the point I needed, thank!!